# How to add multiple tile map levels in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a top down tile based game. i've already created 3 levels for the game but now i have no idea how to load the new levels within the game. The game starts in level 1 and after dealing with all the mobs it starts level 2, but after dealing with all mobs in level 2 it won't load level 3. instead it restarts in level 2. I think my mistake is in the update section of the code, but since i'm still very inexperienced it might be more than just "one" mistake within in that code. 
I'd be glad if anyone could help me

here's my main.py of the code:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tilemap import *

# HUD functions
def draw_player_health(surf, x, y, pct):
    if pct < 0:
        pct = 0
    BAR_LENGTH = 100
    BAR_HEIGHT = 20
    fill = pct * BAR_LENGTH
    outline_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
    fill_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
    if pct > 0.6:
        col = GREEN
    elif pct > 0.3:
        col = YELLOW
    else:
        col = RED
    pg.draw.rect(surf, col, fill_rect)
    pg.draw.rect(surf, BLACK, outline_rect, 2)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()
        self.level = 0

    def draw_text(self, text, font_name, size, color, x, y, align="nw"):
        font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        if align == "nw":
            text_rect.topleft = (x, y)
        if align == "ne":
            text_rect.topright = (x, y)
        if align == "sw":
            text_rect.bottomleft = (x, y)
        if align == "se":
            text_rect.bottomright = (x, y)
        if align == "n":
            text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
        if align == "s":
            text_rect.midbottom = (x, y)
        if align == "e":
            text_rect.midright = (x, y)
        if align == "w":
            text_rect.midleft = (x, y)
        if align == "center":
            text_rect.center = (x, y)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
        self.map_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'maps')
        sfx_folder = path.join(game_folder, "sfx")
        music_folder = path.join(game_folder, "music")
        self.title_font = path.join(img_folder, "ZOMBIE.TTF")
        self.hud_font = path.join(img_folder, "Impacted2.0.ttf")
        self.dim_screen = pg.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert_alpha()
        self.dim_screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 180))
        self.player_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PLAYER_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.mob_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, MOB_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.wall_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, WALL_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.wall_img = pg.transform.scale(self.wall_img, (TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.bullet_images = {}
        self.bullet_images["lg"] = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, BULLET_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.bullet_images["sm"] = pg.transform.scale(self.bullet_images["lg"], (10, 10))
        self.splat = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, SPLAT)).convert_alpha()
        self.splat = pg.transform.scale(self.splat, (64, 64))
        self.gun_flashes = []
        for img in MUZZLE_FLASHES:
            self.gun_flashes.append(pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, img)).convert_alpha())
        self.item_images = {}
        for item in ITEM_IMAGES:
            self.item_images[item] = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, ITEM_IMAGES[item])).convert_alpha()
        # lighting effect
        self.fog = pg.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.fog.fill(NIGHT_COLOR)
        self.light_mask = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, LIGHT_MASK)).convert_alpha()
        self.light_mask = pg.transform.scale(self.light_mask, LIGHT_RADIUS)
        self.light_rect = self.light_mask.get_rect()
        # SOUND LOADING
        pg.mixer.music.load(path.join(music_folder, BG_MUSIC))
        self.effects_sounds = {}
        for type in EFFECTS_SOUNDS:
            self.effects_sounds[type] = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(sfx_folder, EFFECTS_SOUNDS[type]))
        self.weapon_sounds = {}
        for weapon in WEAPON_SOUNDS:
            self.weapon_sounds[weapon] = []
            for sfx in WEAPON_SOUNDS[weapon]:
                s = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(sfx_folder, sfx))
                s.set_volume(0.2)
                self.weapon_sounds[weapon].append(s)
        self.zombie_moan_sounds = []
        for sfx in ZOMBIE_MOAN_SOUNDS:
            s = pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(sfx_folder, sfx))
            s.set_volume(0.2)
            self.zombie_moan_sounds.append(s)
        self.player_hit_sounds = []
        for sfx in PLAYER_HIT_SOUNDS:
            self.player_hit_sounds.append(pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(sfx_folder, sfx)))
        self.zombie_hit_sounds = []
        for sfx in ZOMBIE_HIT_SOUNDS:
            self.zombie_hit_sounds.append(pg.mixer.Sound(path.join(sfx_folder, sfx)))



    def new(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.items = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.map = Tiled_Map(path.join(self.map_folder, 'level1.tmx'))
        self.map_image = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_image.get_rect()
        # for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        #   for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        #        if tile == '1':
        #            Wall(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'M':
        #            Mob(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'P':
        #            self.player = Player(self, col, row)
        for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
            obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2, tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)
            if tile_object.name == "player":
                self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "zombie":
               Mob(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "wall":
                Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y, tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
            if tile_object.name in ["health", "shotgun", "m_gun", "desert_eagle"]:
                Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
        self.draw_debug = False
        self.paused = False
        self.night = False
        self.effects_sounds["level_start"].play()

    def new_2(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.items = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.map = Tiled_Map(path.join(self.map_folder, 'level2.tmx'))
        self.map_image = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_image.get_rect()
        # for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        #   for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        #        if tile == '1':
        #            Wall(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'M':
        #            Mob(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'P':
        #            self.player = Player(self, col, row)
        for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
            obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2, tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)
            if tile_object.name == "player":
                self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "zombie":
               Mob(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "wall":
                Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y, tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
            if tile_object.name in ["health", "shotgun", "m_gun", "desert_eagle"]:
                Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
        self.draw_debug = False
        self.paused = False
        self.night = False
        self.effects_sounds["level_start"].play()

    def new_3(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.items = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.map = Tiled_Map(path.join(self.map_folder, 'level3.tmx'))
        self.map_image = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_image.get_rect()
        # for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        #   for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        #        if tile == '1':
        #            Wall(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'M':
        #            Mob(self, col, row)
        #        if tile == 'P':
        #            self.player = Player(self, col, row)
        for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
            obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2, tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)
            if tile_object.name == "player":
                self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "zombie":
               Mob(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)
            if tile_object.name == "wall":
                Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y, tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
            if tile_object.name in ["health", "shotgun", "m_gun", "desert_eagle"]:
                Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
        self.draw_debug = False
        self.paused = False
        self.night = False
        self.effects_sounds["level_start"].play()

    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
        self.playing = True
        pg.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0  # fix for Python 2.x
            self.events()
            if not self.paused:
                self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # Game over?
        if len(self.mobs) == 0:
            self.new_2()
            if len(self.mobs) == 0:
                self.new_3()
        # update portion of the game loop
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.camera.update(self.player)
        # player hits item
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.items, False, collide_hit_rect)
        for hit in hits:
            if hit.type == "health" and self.player.health < PLAYER_HEALTH:
                hit.kill()
                self.effects_sounds["health_up"].play()
                self.player.add_health(HEALTH_PACK_AMOUNT)
            if hit.type == "shotgun":
                hit.kill()
                self.player.weapon = "shotgun"
                self.effects_sounds["gun_pickup"].play()
            if hit.type == "m_gun":
                hit.kill()
                self.player.weapon = "m_gun"
                self.effects_sounds["gun_pickup"].play()
            if hit.type == "desert_eagle":
                hit.kill()
                self.player.weapon = "desert_eagle"
                self.effects_sounds["gun_pickup"].play()

        # mobs hit player
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.mobs, False, collide_hit_rect)
        for hit in hits:
            if random() < 0.7:
                choice(self.player_hit_sounds).play()
            self.player.health -= MOB_DAMAGE
            hit.vel = vec(0, 0)
            if self.player.health <= 0:
                self.playing = False
            if hits:
                self.player.hit()
                self.player.pos += vec(MOB_KNOCKBACK, 0).rotate(-hits[0].rot)
        # bullet hit mobs
        hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.mobs, self.bullets, False, True)
        for mob in hits:
            # hit.health -= WEAPONS[self.player.weapon]["damage"] * len(hits[hit])
            for bullet in hits[mob]:
                mob.health -= bullet.damage
            mob.vel = vec(0, 0)

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def render_fog(self):
        # draw the light mask (gradient) onto the fog image
        self.fog.fill(NIGHT_COLOR)
        self.light_rect.center = self.camera.apply(self.player).center
        self.fog.blit(self.light_mask, self.light_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.fog, (0, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_MULT)

    def draw(self):
        pg.display.set_caption("{:.2f}".format(self.clock.get_fps()))
        # self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.screen.blit(self.map_image, self.camera.apply_rect(self.map_rect))
        # self.draw_grid()
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            if isinstance(sprite, Mob):
                sprite.draw_health()
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
            if self.draw_debug:
                pg.draw.rect(self.screen, CYAN, self.camera.apply_rect(sprite.rect), 1)
        if self.draw_debug:
            for wall in self.walls:
                pg.draw.rect(self.screen, CYAN, self.camera.apply_rect(wall.rect), 1)
        # pg.draw.rect(self.screen, WHITE, self.player.hit_rect, 2)
        if self.night:
            self.render_fog()
        # HUD functions
        draw_player_health(self.screen, 10, 10, self.player.health / PLAYER_HEALTH)
        self.draw_text("Zombies: {}".format(len(self.mobs)), self.hud_font,
                       30, WHITE, WIDTH - 10, 10, align="ne")
        if self.paused:
            self.screen.blit(self.dim_screen, (0, 0))
            self.draw_text("PAUSED", self.title_font, 105, RED, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, align="center")
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        # catch all events here
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pg.K_h:
                    self.draw_debug = not self.draw_debug
                if event.key == pg.K_p:
                    self.paused = not self.paused
                if event.key == pg.K_n:
                    self.night = not self.night

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass


    def show_go_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.draw_text("GAME OVER", self.title_font, 100,
                       RED, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, align="center")
        self.draw_text("Press a key to start", self.title_font, 75, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4, align="center")
        pg.display.flip()
        self.wait_for_key()

    def wait_for_key(self):
        pg.event.wait()
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.quit()
                if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                    waiting = False

# create the game object
g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] after dealing with all mobs in level 2 it won't load level 3. instead it restarts in level 2. I think my mistake is in the update section of the code, [...]

Of course. See the following liens of code:

> ```py
> class Game:
>    # [...]
>
>    def update(self):
>        # Game over?
>        if len(self.mobs) == 0:
>            self.new_2()
>            if len(self.mobs) == 0:
>                self.new_3()
> ```

`self.new_3()` will never be invoked. If `len(self.mobs) == 0` is fulfilled, the `self.new_2()` is executed and `self.mobs` is initialized.

Add the number of the level (`self.current_level`) to the class `Game`. Increment the  level in `update` and invoke either `new_2` or `new_3` dependent on `self.current_level`. e.g.:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
        self.current_level = 1

    # [...]

    def update(self):
        # Game over?
        if len(self.mobs) == 0:
            self.current_level += 1
            if self.current_level == 2:
                self.new_2()
            else:
                self.new_3()
```

With this approach it is easy to add and load further levels.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. it's really a great community over here, makes learning new things so much easier, thank you again

Comment: yes it works, i can add levels and i can play them all :) but the thing is, after i compiled it to an .exe file via pyinstaller it only loads in the first level. after beating the first level it crahes. error message in the console says it's still trying to load the png files from my desktop. i tried changing the img_source within the tmx file itself but it wouldn't work. any solution?